# Is there an os package equivalent of path.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, filepath, yarnpkg

I'm trying to find an OS package equivalent way of `path.resolve(__dirname, '../bin')`. I want my code to work in all possible types of environments, and so i though though using the OS package would be best suited for this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using `path.join` or `path.resolve` will take care of the directory separator, it will be compatible with any OS as long as you don't hardcode the directory separator. So there's no need to use an additional package.

Don't use `../bin`, instead, use.

```
path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'bin')
```

The `OS` built-in module does not provide a way to resolve paths, the `path` module takes care of that.

> The `path.join()` method joins all given path segments together using **the platform-specific separator as a delimiter**, then normalizes the resulting path.

Comment: I will try this, but Is there an os equivalent?

Comment: what do you mean by OS equivalent? Why do you need an equivalent if that's already multi OS.

Comment: I guess the question is, will the path.resolve() work for every evironment? Test, Dev, Prod, and multi-os?

Comment: yes it does, will work as long as you don't hardcode directory separators.

Comment: This is good advice. However, `path` does handle directory separator normalizationn. e.g. `path.resolve('C:/Users') === 'C:\\Users'`.

Comment: As long as you don't use hardcoded directory separators `path` will work fine.